# A simple jQuery/AJAX query

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Okay, I didn't do jQuery for a while and I feel like I am doing some really banal mistake, but can't seem to find it.

I'd like to put the html file, using ajax,to my index.php when the document is ready without actually preloading the website.

So, the button in .php file:

```
  <button class="dropposts">Post a Comment..</button>
```

And the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.dropposts').on('click', function() {
        $.ajax({ url: 'comment_form.html',
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(response) 
            { $('.comment-form').html(response); }
        });
    }):
}):
```

This is extremely simple; my file is in the root site folder, in the `comment_form.html` to be specific. Now, when I click the button nothing happens. Why? Am I missing something really basic?

Comment: You should use jQuery Load : http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: Remove the `dataType: html` and then try.

Comment: maybe the colons are crashing it? you should use semicolins to close the last 2 functions...

Comment: Did you look in the browser error console for errors?

Comment: In the future, please learn simple debugging techniques before coming to StackOverflow.  The very first thing you should do when your JS isn't working is to check the browser error console and see if it reports any errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a syntax error in your code, You used `:` instead of `;`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.dropposts').on('click', function() {
        $.ajax({ url: 'comment_form.html',
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(response) 
            { $('.comment-form').html(response); }
        });
    });//changed here
}); //changed here
```

Comment: Yep, that would be a syntax error (if that's in the real code, not just an artifact in the posted question).  Did the OP not even bother to look in the error console for errors?

Comment: Yes, it was just simple as that. Thanks!